# How to loop all the elements that match the regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the case:
I want to find the elements which match the regex...

> targetText = "SomeT1extSomeT2extSomeT3extSomeT4extSomeT5extSomeT6ext"

and I use the regex in javascript like this

```
reg = new RegExp(/e(.*?)e/g);   
var result = reg.exec(targetText);
```

and I only get the first one, but not the follow....
I can get the T1 only, but not T2, T3 ... ...

Comment: Can anyone suggest a for loop way to do it?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```js
function doSomethingWith(result) {
  console.log(result)
}

const targetText = "SomeT1extSomeT2extSomeT3extSomeT4extSomeT5extSomeT6ext"
const reg = /e(.*?)e/g;
let result;
while ((result = reg.exec(targetText)) !== null) {
  doSomethingWith(result);
}
```

Comment: Note that the regex must be assigned to an object before using in this manner: `/e(.*?)e/.exec(...)` will give an infinite loop.

Comment: I got infinite loop for document.body.innerHTML

Comment: @RaviParekh: did you add the `/g` modifier?

Comment: @chaos, Thanks, I had not added /g global. which led to infinite.

Comment: For posterity's sake, the RegExp needs to be declared outside of the while loop; otherwise you'll still get an infinite loop.

Comment: You can also shorten the while expression: `while(result = reg.exec(targetText)) {` leveraging the "false" resolve.

Comment: IMPORTANT: You need to set the read/write property of the regex `reg.lastIndex = result.index + 1;` at the end of the loop in order to move to the next match.

Comment: @Redtopia You must only increment lastIndex manually (`reg.lastIndex = result.index + 1;`) if you are not using the `g` (global) flag in your regex. The global flag will automatically move to the next match, however, the disadvantage is that if you want to re-use a global regex, you must reset `reg.lastIndex = 0;` before you match a new string.

Answer (score 69):

Three approaches depending on what you want to do with it:

- Loop through each match: [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/match)

  ```
  targetText.match(/e(.*?)e/g).forEach((element) => {
     // Do something with each element
  });
  ```
- Loop through and replace each match on the fly: [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/replace)

  ```
  const newTargetText = targetText.replace(/e(.*?)e/g, (match, $1) => {
    // Return the replacement leveraging the parameters.
  });
  ```
- Loop through and do something on the fly: [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

  ```
  const regex = /e(.*?)e/g;  // Must be declared outside the while expression, 
                             // and must include the global "g" flag.

  let result;
  while(result = regex.exec(targetText)) {
    // Do something with result[0].
  }
  ```

Comment: Ironically my Lint wants to put `==` in place of `=` in the while expression.

Comment: To make eslint accept the single `=` the assignment can be surrounded by parentheses like so:
`while ((result = regex.exec(targetText)))`

Comment: In the second example there, is match a key word or a variable? And if it's a variable what is it holding?

Comment: @ColePerry `match` is the whole RegExp match, and `$1` is the first capture group `()`, in that example, only one.

Comment: Here, only replace will work, because in Node.js the global match/exec returns only total match without groups.

Answer (score 13):

Try using [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on the string instead of exec(), though you could loop with exec as well.  Match should give you the all the matches at one go.  I think you can omit the global specifier as well.

```
reg = new RegExp(/e(.*?)e/);   
var matches = targetText.match(reg);
```

Comment: Don't link to w3schools. They are unaffiliated with W3C and have a lot of wrong information. See http://w3fools.com.

Comment: @MindVirus - if you'd bother to check, they've cleaned up a lot of the stuff that w3fools.com pointed out.  I still use them as a quick, though not definitive, resource.  Much like one might use a cheat sheet over K&R C to look up something simple.

Comment: As an intermediate dev, I've already encountered a good half dozen clear errors at w3schools.  They're off my party list.

Comment: MDN reference for `String.prototype.match` — https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: To clarify the answer, the global specifier _is_ understood by `match`.

Comment: the difference is that you don't get the captured groups with `String.match`, while `RegExp.exec` does.

Answer (score 4):

I kept getting infinite loops while following the advice above, for example:

```
var reg = /e(.*?)e/g;
var result;
while((result = reg.exec(targetText)) !== null) {
    doSomethingWith(result);
}
```

The object that was assigned to `result` each time was:

```
["", "", index: 50, input: "target text", groups: undefined]
```

So in my case I edited the above code to:

```
const reg = /e(.*?)e/g;
let result = reg.exec(targetText);
while(result[0] !== "") {
    doSomethingWith(result);
    result = reg.exec(targetText);
}
```

Comment: that's because of the regex. you have let to accept empty strings by putting a question mark

Answer (score 2):

```
targetText = "SomeT1extSomeT2extSomeT3extSomeT4extSomeT5extSomeT6ext"    
reg = new RegExp(/e(.*?)e/g);   
var result;
while (result = reg.exec(targetText))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. In JS regex cannot extract groups with global flag, so the user will receive only total match.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the String.replace method to loop through all elements.

```js
result = [];
 // Just get all numbers
"SomeT1extSomeT2extSomeT3ext".replace(/(\d+?)/g, function(wholeMatch, num) {
  // act here or after the loop...
  console.log(result.push(num));
  return wholeMatch;
});
console.log(result); // ['1', '2', '3']
```

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I did this in a console session (Chrome).

```
> let reg = /[aeiou]/g;
undefined
> let text = "autoeciously";
undefined
> matches = text.matches(reg);
(7) ["a", "u", "o", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
> matches.forEach(x =>console.log(x));
a
u
o
e
i
o
u
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @tvanfosson suggested in his answer, I'm adding the modified version for someone who only needs to get all matchings.

```
var targetText = "SomeT1extSomeT2extSomeT3extSomeT4extSomeT5extSomeT6ext";
var reg = /e(.*?)e/g;
var ss = targetText.match(reg); // ss = "eT1e,eT2e,eT3e,eT4e,eT5e,eT6e"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was actually dealing with this issue. I prefer Lambda functions for about everything.

```
reg = /e(.*?)e/gm;   
targetText.match(reg).forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

Comment: this only found the first match.