# C# Regular Expression Attribute not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using the [RegularExpression attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify multiple email addresses on one input in my view model.  The ErrorMessage keeps coming up on field.  I have validated my RegEx on 5 different online test sites and they all test positive.

Here is my code:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;\s]+\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*){0,7}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.  For multiple addresses please use a comma or semicolon to separate the email addresses.")]
public string EmailAddresses { get; set; }
```

If I enter an email address it works, if I enter two email addresses without spaces it works, but if I add a space it breaks.  I added the '\s' to include white spaces and it does work on the online testers I have tried but it will not work in my application.

The expected valid result should be:
    'test@test.com, test2@test.com, test3@test.com'

However, this it coming back as invalid.  If I use the exact same sequence with no spaces it is valid.

Kendo UI is checking the validation of the form before sending it to the controller.

Any help is very appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\s` also allows newlines, vertical tabs, form feeds, and a couple of others. Are you sure you want those included in your acceptable matches?

Comment: how does it "break?"  give us some example inputs and outputs vs. what you expect.  Is it the regex breaking or some code behind logic?

Comment: @ps2goat, here are some examples....

    test@test.com, test2@test.com; test3@test.com  (this is invalid)
    test@test.com,test2@test.com;test3@test.com    (this is valid)

Comment: @KennethK., I was using RegExp cheatsheet for white spaces.  I do not want newlines

Comment: @C.Daniel, can you edit your question and put the expected data in there?  use the tick mark " ` " (above the tab key) to denote where a value starts and ends, similar to code markup, so we know if a trailing space is included or not.

Comment: I have edited the post to show what I expect and also put in that Kendo UI is validating the form.

Comment: As you established with your online testers your regular expression is correct. So what does not work? Is there a error message you are getting? What do you do leading up to the error message? What is the relevant code? It looks like you set up your validation incorrectly, but you are not giving any details of how you set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

`"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"`

Comment: Same issue.  When I add a space the regex fails.

Comment: Its strange,because this pattern tested with spaces and all possible variants of emails. Are you want to place more than one email in one text field on page?

Comment: Correct, I am allowing them to place more than one email address in one text field separated by commas or semi-colons.  While I know there are other options, this is the option the product owner wanted and won't bend on.

Comment: so, it seems that you need smth like loop for all input pslitted by space...but how to do it reg exp?..try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222045/how-to-loop-all-the-elements-that-match-the-regex

Comment: Would this help since he is doing it in JavaScript?  Mine is being done as a RegularExpression attribute in my C# View Model.  A for loop wouldn't help there....would it?  I am new to C#

Comment: you can also check your rules onclient with javascript solution, and then send data to server if (and only if your) data is valid. another way is to skip attribute, send data to server, split it to array of strings and then validate each string in that array  useng regexp in c#

Comment: or, which is the best solution - you can combine these two approaches

Comment: Kendo UI is validating the form.  I updated the initial post to reflect this.

Comment: so you have solved client-side validation, there is only server-side waiting. does manual validation not meets your criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  "@" symbol. I tested your pattern at http://regexstorm.net/tester and it is correct match for test@test.com, test2@test.com, test3@test.com . Use construct below

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
  [RegularExpression("\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;\s]+\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*){0,7}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.  For multiple addresses please use a comma or semicolon to separate the email addresses.")]
  public string EmailAddresses { get; set; }

}
```

For it to work in ASP.NET MVC Framework ensure you do the have the following on the view

```
<input type="text" id ="EmailAddresses" name="EmailAddresses"/>
```

The `id` and `name` attributes are required for it to validate. You can do this manually as above or use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddresses)` which will create the `id` and `name` attributes for you

Comment: What does "@" symbol have to do with anything?

Comment: @zespri, I said he does not need @ symbol. It isn't the cause.  If you read the answer I said   " For it to work in ASP.NET MVC Framework ensure you do the have the following on the view...  "   and provided what is required in the view. The "@" symbol is used to tell the compiler, to keep the string literal as is. It isn't required in this attribute because the compiler will not escape anything and will be used as is. In this context @ is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  In the end it had nothing to do with C#.  The problem was I was using Kendo UI on the front end, as updated in the main post.  Keno UI had to also receive the RegEx update sent by Andrew to solve the issue.  I will make Andrew as the correct solution as his RegEx did work for me.  I was totally turn around by the server side/client side difference as I am new to this.  Thank you all for your help.