# Capture String between String Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have looked a bunch of example on this site, but still can't completely get this right. I am trying to grab only stuff between `>` and `<`.
Example String:

```
<div class='col-lg-12 hintDisplay'>slavery <b>ALSO USE</b> human trafficking</div>
```

First I did:

```
var regexp = />(.*?)</g;
var matches_array = item.toString().match(regexp);
console.log(matches_array);
```

and got:

```
>slavery <,>ALSO USE<,> human trafficking<
```

Then I read more and tried:

```
var regexp = /(>)(.*?)(?=<)/g;
var matches_array = item.toString().match(regexp);
console.log(matches_array);
```

and now:

```
>slavery ,>ALSO USE,> human trafficking
```

I couldn't find a document on how to get rid of the leading `>`. So how do I grab on the stuff inbetween `>` and `<`?

Comment: Why not parse the string as html and then use `jquery` to extract the content you need? In case of regex, you need to remove the parenthesis around `>`. `/>(.*?)(?=<)/g` so it's not captured.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try when I get back to my desk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in my opinion you should use the build-in **HTML parser and use JQuery** or something similar to get your text out of the HTML.

Some reasons why you **shouldn't regex HTML** can be found over here:

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.

[RegEx match open tags except HTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use your advice. I am not going to select your answer as the correct answer because what if the next person text is not `HTML`. This is the correct answer for my situation but not for the question. Once again, thank!

Comment: Your question is about html parsing using javascript, this is the correct answer and should be accepted as such.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I like to do a regex like:

```
var regexp = />([^<]+)</;
```

This says start with a > and then at least 1 non < followed by a <

Trying to use .*? usually leads to the kind of issues you are running into :)

https://regex101.com/r/UJrVWd/1

Comment: I am still getting `>slavery <,>ALSO USE<,> human trafficking< (15:20:27:481 | null)` using your solution.

Comment: Without `g` `>slavery <,slavery  (15:25:09:977 | null)`. Only the first match.

Comment: check out the regex101 link, it looks like it's working.  Maybe I'm missing something specific to javascript here

Comment: Yea, it looks good in that link, but my `console.log()` output looks like the full match instead of the group result.

Comment: OP, you are printing the full match instead of the captured group to console

Comment: Okay, how do I print the captured group?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression   I think this does the trick or perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222045/how-to-loop-all-the-elements-that-match-the-regex

Comment: Actually, I am printing all the content of the `Array` that's storing the `Matches`.

Comment: I already tried the first link before posting this question and it didn't get the job done. The second link you posted is right on and exactly what I needed to make the capture group act the way it was designed to. Thanks.