# Getting hash values from regex loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON object as seen below, where I would like to loop over entries that match `u[0-9][0-9][0-9]`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222045/how-to-loop-all-the-elements-that-match-the-regex) is close to what I am looking for, but what I want is to get the hash values.

If I do:

```
const config = toml('config.toml')

config.match(/u[0-9][0-9][0-9]/g).forEach((element) => {
  console.log(element)
});
```

Then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: config.match is not a function
```

## Question

How would I loop over this JSON object and get the value from the keys that match `u[0-9][0-9][0-9]`?

```
{ conf:
   { url: 'https://example.com',
     u150: 'Log entry severity',
     u160: 'Log entry',
     d105: 'Check interval',
     d107: 'Incident cool down time',
     d120: 'Incident impact',
     d130: 'Incident urgency',
     d180: 'Implementeret i Produktion' },
  projects:
   { d1:
      { page_id: 104637,
        page_title: 'Moni' },
     k1:
      { page_id: 99999,
        page_title: 'Moni' } } }
```

Comment: I'm quite confused about what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to get the values where the keys match `conf.u[0-9]{3}`?

Comment: Well, `match` is a string method. You are probably interested in `Object.entries()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const config = { conf:
   { url: 'https://example.com',
     u150: 'Log entry severity',
     u160: 'Log entry',
     d105: 'Check interval',
     d107: 'Incident cool down time',
     d120: 'Incident impact',
     d130: 'Incident urgency',
   }
} // shortened your object

const matches = [];

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.conf))
  {
    if(key.match(/u[0-9][0-9][0-9]/g))
      matches.push({ key, value })
  }
  
console.log(matches)
```

I came up with this idea. Basically I split the object into array of `[key, value]`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment you are trying to use `.match()`, you can just convert your `config.conf` to array and then iterate through it using `Object.keys()`, here is a snippet for what you want:

```js
let config = { conf:
   { url: 'https://example.com',
     u150: 'Log entry severity',
     u160: 'Log entry',
     d105: 'Check interval',
     d107: 'Incident cool down time',
     d120: 'Incident impact',
     d130: 'Incident urgency',
     d180: 'Implementeret i Produktion' },
  projects:
   { d1:
      { page_id: 104637,
        page_title: 'Moni' },
     k1:
      { page_id: 99999,
        page_title: 'Moni' } } }

const conf = {}
const matched = Object.keys(config.conf).filter(el => {
  return el.match(/u[0-9]{3}/g);
}).forEach(el => conf[el] = config.conf[el]);

console.log(conf);
```